# gridpane size and placement to cover entire area from left to right

Tags: java, netbeans

Hello stackoverflow users! I have a question about `gridpanes`. I'm working on a program (picture below) and I'm mostly finished. However, I've run into a few small cosmetic issues.

I've created my title:

```
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    Text scenetitle = new Text("Welcome to the Pizza Palace");
    scenetitle.setFill(Color.RED);
    scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
    grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0);
```

As you can see the title is `Welcome to the Pizza Palace` and I wanted the title to be centered so I entered

```
grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0);
```

because I wanted the title to cover the scene (as displayed in the picture) and I wanted the title to be centered

**Unfortunately**, the title doesn't cover the entire scene in fact it cause the gridpane below it (0,1) where "Each Toppings" is located to expand as the title increases or decreases.

I've run into a similiar issue in the text area for "your orders"

```
// Create a new text area
TextArea orderscreen = new TextArea();
orderscreen.setPrefColumnCount(25);
orderscreen.setPrefRowCount(7);    
grid.add(orderscreen, 0, 4);
```

Once again I set the grid to 0 for the far left and 4 so it would be located under the button but unfortunately as the text area increases so does my toppings.

So how do I go about creating a title or textarea using a gridpane that will cover the entire scene from left to right (like the title in the picture does)?

[image]